# What should the Realm URL be for permission changes?

Tags: realm

I can't seem to figure out the proper URL for performing permission changes.  Following the docs, I can successfully change global permissions for all realms by passing `*` for the URL, but I can't get specific named realm permissions to stick. I am attempting to grant read-only access to realms created by another (admin level) user.

```
[RLMSyncPermissionChange permissionChangeWithRealmURL:@"realms://my.domain.com:9443/~/Realm-Name"
                           userID:@"5443d0cfc457b762e47855ffc3b0732d"
                             read:@YES 
                            write:@NO 
                           manage:@NO];
```

Shows this in the server logs (and in the statusMessage field, with a statusCode of 616):

```
error: permission: Error when processing PermissionChange(id='32455E8C-8...'):
The server is not authoritative for this URL.
```

The URL I am passing is the same as that used to create the Realm. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've deployed the Realm Object Server to an external reachable URL, you need to configure the host(s) for this in the `configuration.yml` under the key `auth:sync_hosts`, if you want to use these external URLs with the client permission API.

This could look like below:

```
auth:
   sync_hosts:
        - my.domain.com:9443
```

Beside that the server will always determine itself to be authoritative for `localhost`. This can be also passed as its IPv4 variant `127.0.0.1` and IPv6 variant `::`.

So alternatively, you can just construct the URL you pass into `RLMSyncPermissionChange` based on that:

```
[RLMSyncPermissionChange permissionChangeWithRealmURL:@"realms://localhost:9443/~/Realm-Name"
                                               userID:@"5443d0cfc457b762e47855ffc3b0732d"
                                                 read:@YES 
                                                write:@NO 
                                               manage:@NO];
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple, thank you very much marius - works like a champ!